# Does bootstrap download jQuery with it?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded bootstrap from getbootstrap.com, and I am doing a basic html website, just one JS file and one CSS file. In the console for my browser, I typed: `$` and it returned: `function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }` . So bootstrap downloaded jQuery with it?

What if I have jQuery referenced on the site by default? will there be any conflicts? How can I know which version of jQuery bootstrap downloaded?

Comment: As sideinfo - you can open the console panel at web dev tools and execute `$().jquery;`, this will return the jquery version (if any)  of the actual site. For e.g.  Stackoverflow, it's currently  1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't include jQuery, you need to add one yourself or use the jquery CDN like their example
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: Thanks, but when I execute $ on the console, it doesn't say that $ is undefined, doesn't that mean that jQuery is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap file contain many js files,such as bootstrap.js,bootstrap.min.js...
these js file need a jquery file to run then extend function,so you need download a jquery file and add your application,In addition,only use jquery file  version correctly,you can load your bootstrap file,and you must load jquery file early than bootstrap js file!otherwise your console will throw errors.

Comment: Thanks William, but how does typing $ not returning undefined?

Comment: you need load your jquery-1.9.1.js file before you load your bootstrap js file!it's very important because bootstrap js file base on jquery-1.9.1.js file